# Execute non-query error

Tags: c#, sql

I have tried to insert some values into a table through my C# code, but every time I execute it, it works until the `ExecuteNonQuery()` and then I get an exception and it breaks. Here is the code:

```
connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Book base.sdf");
connection.Open();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] im = ms.ToArray();

using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Authors (IDN, Surname, Picture, Date of birth, Writer_name) VALUES (@id, @surname, @picture, @date, @name)", connection))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(id.Text);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surname.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(surname.Text);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", im);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Text);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(name.Text);

    Console.WriteLine(com.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

So, what can be the problem?

Comment: What is the exception? Which line?

Comment: Could you please provide exception detail and table schema? At first look what i found is that the connection string is incorrect.

Comment: "Date of birth" with out [ ] could be the culprit. And what is the exception message?

Comment: Adding [] around date of birth was the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need brackets around Date of birth:`, [Date of birth], Writer_name`.

Comment: Yeah, that solved a problem! Thanks a lot, man!

Answer (score 0):

Check that idn is a string and that date of birth is a datetime2 in your table.
Also put date of birth inside square brackets in your query.